# error: no matches for extensions/, Kind=Deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to create deployment on my local kubernetes claster by running the following

```
kubectl create deployment kubernetes-kubectl --image=firstkube:v1
```

I am getting the following response

```
error: no matches for extensions/, Kind=Deployment
```

Here are some details on my local environment

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.1", GitCommit:"3a1c9449a956b6026f075fa3134ff92f7d55f812", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-04T11:52:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:18:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

kubectl get nodes 
NAME             STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready     master    16m       v1.16.6-beta.0
```

My docker version

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please check by updating `kubectl` client version or by running `kubectl run kubernetes-kubectl --image=firstkube:v1` ?

Comment: kubectl run kubernetes-kubectl --image=firstkube:v1
replicationcontroller "kubernetes-kubectl" created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kubectl client and server version are too far apart. As You can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin):

> You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.2 client should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 master. Using the latest version of kubectl helps avoid unforeseen issues.

You should follow the docs on how to upgrade the kubectl [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/).